# SSRS 2012 Authentication

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I recently installed SSRS 2012 Express edition and running the service using LocalSystem as built-in account. However when I want to view on browser `http://localhost/Reports`, it seems to require authentication and I'm not sure what credentials to put here. 
Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Any assistance would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ugh, SSRS authentication... Can you try using IE10+ with "Run as Administrator"? You may still get the popup where you should be able to enter any local admin account. After that you can authorize your user account as SSRS admin - after that you should be able to run IE in user-mode and be able to log in with your own account.

Comment: ok I was able to login using local admin account but now I get following error message on browser: "The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version."